# Chromecast CORS Issue

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a chromecast application which will stream playready assets. But am facing the issue of cors error. I know we have to add cors header to solve this and I have done that.
 [Developing for Chromecast without CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767302/developing-for-chromecast-without-cors)
From the above link I came to know that proxy can be set to chromecast device. Can anyone please tell me how to set proxy to chromecast device so that I can check the request and response through the device. I dont have deep knowledge in server side. So please give me an elaborated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The best way to solve the issue is to put the Receiver application in the same place where the contents are placed.
Works only when the contents are in the same bucket.